# ListView displaying problems

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, alignment

I have a listview that consists three columns. The first one is an ImageView, the second and third one are textviews (see code blow).

I want the list to be aligned like this:

1. the icon and the date should always been shown completely !!
2. the text in the middle should show as much chars as possible
3. the date should always be on the right of the right side

With the XML below it looks ok on my Nexus 4. But on the asus tablet the date should be more on the right and the coloumn in the middle should show more text ([screenshot 1](http://abload.de/img/asustransformerpadlpjkf.jpg)). On the AVD ([screenshot 2](http://abload.de/img/avdnukhg.png)) the coloumn in the middle should be smaller and the date should be shown completely.

Can anyone tell me how to change the XML? Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:src="@drawable/social_chat"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_changed"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
    android:text="@+id/last_changed"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    >
</TextView>
```

Comment: heres a screenshot of my nexus 4. looks good. http://abload.de/img/nexus40vkzt.png

Comment: first thing, dont use "px" .. use "dp"

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head your layout would look something like this.-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/social_chat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_changed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@+id/last_changed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The key here is to use `wrap_content` for the views that just need to keep their size, and set a `weight` for the middle view, which you want to fill the rest of the row.

---

Some useful tips.-

- `fill_parent` is deprecated, use `match_parent` instead
- When a view has no children, you can just close it with `/>`
- `singleLine="true"` is enough to have a singleLined `TextView`
- You'll usually want to use `dp` units instead of `px`

Comment: Glad it helped :) By the way, don't forget to consider upvoting/accepting the answer/s that helped you the better, as it may be useful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

This should do your job. I have put the imageview on the parents left, the date on the parents right and the label to the rightof image and to the left of date.It should work fine for you. Margins , padding please put yourself

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/social_chat" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_changed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/last_changed"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
    android:singleLine="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Then please accept the answer..(you will have to click the tick mark against my answer to accept it)